# How can I get Windows to add the date in a .LOG file automatically?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, logfiles

I used to know a trick so that every time I opened a text file in Notepad it would be populated with the current date and time and a pseudo-linebreak (i.e. `=============`).

I thought it was just calling the file `whatever.LOG` but it doesn't seem to work.

I was on Windows XP last time I knew this to work, now I'm on Windows 7. It seems like a pretty archaic feature but why would it be removed?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: When exactly do you want the date appended to the top of the text file? When you open it or when it is first created?

Comment: Please see the answers below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type
.LOG
on the first line, and then press ENTER to move to the next line.

Save the file.  Each time you open it, it adds the time/date stamp.

More info here:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;260563

Answer (score 2):

The process is outlined in this Microsoft article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260563

The first line of your file must be `.LOG` and it's important that it be in upper case. I just tried it in Windows 7 and it still works.

Comment: Thanks - accepted because you're two minutes ahead of Kerry

Comment: @Matt, if that is the basis for accepting the answer, you should know that Kerry's answer is two minutes **older** than Mark's.

Comment: @iglvzx is right, but I swear that we wrote our answers independently. I took 2 minutes to test the answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom It happens. :) Stack Exchange will show a small notification when another user has posted an answer while you are writing one. I'm not sure it goes away by itself. When there's a single, set answer to a question, it is not too rare for people to post the same thing at nearly the same time.

Comment: It was basically a coin-toss to decide since both answers gave pretty much identical information. I made a mistake on the timing part, I've now rectified it.

Answer (score 0):

I remembered! All you've gotta do is start your file contents with `.LOG`.

```
.LOG

22:25 18/01/2012
Something happened I should make a note of.

22:26 18/01/2012
Another thing has happened!

22:26 18/01/2012
Not again!
```